# NPE raised by a RESTEasy Exception Mapper

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

Here's what I'm trying to do, it seems that I'm missing something about the RESTEasy documentation so thank's in advance for helping.

My team decided to **ALWAYS return a 200 (ok)** status to our REST exposed services (exclusivly JSON). so , to do that we decied to rely on the Exception Mapper mechanisme provided by the RESTEasy framework.

Which means that for a given (business or technical) issue within our code we raise our Special RuntimeException then the mapper has to build an ErrorBean as a Response Body.

Here's the most important parts of the code to do that.

Resource Method raising the Special Exception :

```
    @GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@BadgerFish
@ApiOperation(value = "gets all documents of the current user", notes = "gets all documents of the current user", responseClass = "com.cdc.pcp.api.bean.DocumentVO", multiValueResponse=true)
public Response getAllDocuments() throws PCPResourceException {

    try {
        UserInformation userInformation = userService.getUserInformation(getUsername());
        List<ParapheurNodeInformation> nodesInformations = new ArrayList<ParapheurNodeInformation>();
        nodesInformations = taskService.getTasksReadyToSignOrValidate(userInformation);
        int i = 0/0;
        return Response.ok(BeanConverter.toDocumentVOList(nodesInformations)).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste des documents pour l'utilisateur : " + getUsername() , e);

        throw new PCPResourceException(e.getMessage(), "Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste des documents pour l'utilisateur", ResourceErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR, e);         
    }
}
```

Special Exception Mapper :

```
@Provider
public class PCPResourceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<PCPResourceException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(PCPResourceException exception) {
    ErrorBean eb =new ErrorBean();
    eb.setDeveloperMessage("lol");
    eb.setErrorCode(0);
    eb.setGeneration(new Date());
    eb.setGravity(Gravity.ERROR);
    eb.setMoreInfoUrl("lolll");
    eb.setUserFriendlyMessage("fuck");
    GenericEntity<ErrorBean> e = new GenericEntity<ErrorBean>(eb) {
    };
    return Response.ok(e).build();
}

}
```

The Log

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.WriterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:460)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.executeExceptionMapper(SynchronousDispatcher.java:349)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:373)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:362)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.cdc.pcp.api.util.ApiOriginFilter.doFilter(ApiOriginFilter.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Mapper code to first set the Status and then, put the Error Bean within the header of the response :

```
return Response.status(Status.OK).header(HEADER_RESPONSE_PARAPHEUR_ERROR, gson.toJson(errorBean)).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer but it's a start. When I took a look at this line:
`org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:460)`
here: [SynchronousDispatcher](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.1.0.GA/org/jboss/resteasy/core/SynchronousDispatcher.java), I could assume that only thing that could be null at that point is: `ResteasyProviderFactory`.

I guess you are missing some dependency or didn't register this provider factory.

> ExceptionMappers are registered in the same way as MessageBodyReaders and MessageBodyWriters: by scanning through the RESTEasy provider context-param (if you are deploying in a WAR file), or programmatically through the ResteasyProviderFactory class.
>   From:

Comment: The mapper is registred correctly and after digging in the code I found a line which tries to loop over some annotations but the annotations list is null which is the origine of the NPE. What I(m missing is which annotations are required and why there's no a if (annotation!=null) before the loop. That leads me to suppose that those annotations are required or may be a bug.